# How to retrieve the attribute values from the tags in XML File

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xml-attribute, xmlelement

**Edit**: Updated the XML file

**Requirement:**

Need to read attribute name value from all the tag.

**Sample XML FIle:**

```
<ObjectConfig>
   <ObjectAttribute name="A">
       <ListenerRule>   
            <Reference name="B">
       <ListenerRule>
  <AttributeSource name="C">        
    <ApplicationRef>        
        <Reference name="D">
    </ApplicationRef>
    <RuleRef>
        <Reference name="E">    
    </RuleRef>
  </AttributeSource>
<AttributeTargets >
    <AttributeTarget name="F">
       <ApplicationRef>
           <Reference name="G">
       <ApplicationRef>
</AttributeTargets>
  </ObjectAttribute>

<ObjectAttribute name="H">
       <ListenerRule>   
            <Reference name="I">
       <ListenerRule>
  <AttributeSource name="J">        
    <ApplicationRef>        
        <Reference name="K">
    </ApplicationRef>
    <RuleRef>
        <Reference name="L">    
    </RuleRef>
  </AttributeSource>
<AttributeTargets >
    <AttributeTarget name="M">
       <ApplicationRef>
           <Reference name="N">
       <ApplicationRef>
</AttributeTargets>
  </ObjectAttribute>
</ObjectConfig>
```

**Check the code and its description below**

This is my java Code. I am able to fetch the name attribute for ObjectAttribute tag. Looking to fetch name attribute for all other tags inside ObjectConfig.

```
  import java.io.*;
  import javax.xml.parsers.*;
  import org.w3c.dom.*;

  public class XmlTest {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
     File inputFile = new File("xmlPrueba.xml");
     DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = 
     DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
     DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
     Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
     doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
     System.out.println("Root element :"+doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName()); 
     
     NodeList ObjectAttributeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("ObjectAttribute");
     for (int temp = 0; temp < ObjectAttributeList.getLength(); temp++) {
        Node ObjectAttributeNode = ObjectAttributeList.item(temp);  
        if (ObjectAttributeNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
           Element ObjectAttributeElement = (Element) ObjectAttributeNode;
            System.out.println("Object Attribute Name : "  
              + ObjectAttributeElement.getAttribute("name"));

        NodeList ListenerRuleList = ObjectAttributeNode.getChildNodes();
         for (int i = 0; i < ListenerRuleList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node ListenerRuleNode = ListenerRuleList.item(i);  
        if (ListenerRuleNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
           NodeList ListenerReferenceRuleList = ListenerRuleNode.getChildNodes();
           for(int j=0; j<ListenerReferenceRuleList.getLength(); j++){
              Node ListenerReferenceRuleNode = ListenerReferenceRuleList.item(j);
              if(ListenerReferenceRuleNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                 Element ListenerReferenceRuleElement = (Element) ListenerReferenceRuleNode;
                     System.out.println("Listener Attribute Name : "  
              + ListenerReferenceRuleElement.getAttribute("name"));
              }
              
           }
        }
         }
          
        }
     }
     
  } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

}
}

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: follow this tutorial it answers your question with examples: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parse_document.htm

Answer (score 0):

First, I put a root node around your XML document (an XML document needs a root node to be [well-formed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document)):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <Object name="a"/>
    <Object name="b"/>
    <Object name="c">
        <Attribute name="atnameC"/>
    </Object>
    <Object name="d">
        <Attribute name="atnameD"/>
    </Object>
</root>
```

How the root node is named (e.g. `root`, `Objects` or something else) does not matter here, it just needs to span around all other nodes.

---

Your code tries to print the attribute `displayname` of the `Object` tag.
Either you wanted to print out the attribute `name` of the `Object` tag or you thought you could print out the `Attribute` tags with this.

To print out the attribute `name` of the `Object` tag, you could do something like this:

```java
System.out.println("Object name: " + objectElement.getAttribute("name"));
```

To get the `name` attribute of the `Attribute` tags, you'll have to call `getElementsByTagName` on the `Object` element (e.g. `eElement`). Then you can iterate through the `NodeList` and retrieve the `name` attribute of the `Attribute` tags.

```java
NodeList attributeNodeList = eElement.getElementsByTagName("Attribute");
for (int attrNum = 0; attrNum < attributeNodeList.getLength(); attrNum++) {
    Node attributeNode = attributeNodeList.item(attrNum);
    System.out.println("Object " + eElement.getAttribute("name") + " has Attribute: "
            + attributeNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue());
}
```